# how do I handle click on map label in android?

Tags: android, maps

Is it possible to handle click on labels (citys' names) in android MapView or MapFragment ? And how can I do it if it is possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An info window allows you to display information to the user when they tap on a marker. Only one info window is displayed at a time. If a user clicks on another marker, the current info window will be hidden and the new info window will be displayed.

An info window is drawn oriented against the device's screen, centered above its associated marker. The default info window contains the title in bold, with the (optional) snippet text below the title.

You are also able to customize the contents and design of info windows. To do this, you must create a concrete implementation of the **InfoWindowAdapter** interface and then call **GoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter()** with your implementation. The interface contains two methods for you to implement: **getInfoWindow(Marker)** and **getInfoContents(Marker)**. The API will first call **getInfoWindow(Marker)** and if null is returned, it will then call **getInfoContents(Marker)**. If this also returns null, then the default info window will be used.

The first of these (**getInfoWindow()**) allows you to provide a view that will be used for the entire info window. The second of these (**getInfoContents()**) allows you to just customize the contents of the window but still keep the default info window frame and background.

More information go to this link:[Google Maps Android API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows)

Comment: As far as I understand I should put some markers on the map in order to handle clicks on them. Am I right ? I'd like to do it without any markers. There are a labels for countries and cities on the map. I'd like to open an activity or replace fragment with args if user tap on this label...

Answer (score 1):

You should go to this Link:[Google Maps Utility API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm-medium=gplus&utm_campaign=mdr-devdocs).